# Connecting Foreign key models with Django signal

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I'm trying to build a Django signal whose sender is a Model (called Bacteria) and whose receiver is a model (called Bumblebee). These models have a foreign key relationship through the following:

```
class Bumblebee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Bacteria(models.Model):
    bumblebee = models.ForeignKey(Bumblebee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I'm building this post_save signal to listen for a Bacteria being created, how do I then call fields of Bumblebee? This is what I have but it's not working.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Bacteria)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    bumblebee = Bacteria.bumblebee
    print(bumblebee.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the currently created instance of Bacteria.

```
   @receiver(post_save, sender=Bacteria)
   def my_handler(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
     if created:
        bumblebee = instance.bumblebee
        print(bumblebee.name)
```

Here instance is the object of Bacteria.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. One more question - if I was then going to try to reference one additional model, User, which has a FK relationship with Bumblebee, could I do this all in one single signal that starts with Bacteria?

Comment: Yes you can do that in same signal, using instance.user

Comment: Thank you! And one final question (I promise, but these are so helpful). If the instance has a field that is not a Foreign Key with another object, but the name is the same, can I use == to somehow connect them inside this signal? Some like 'if instance.name == Insect', and then call Insect?

Comment: You want to use another model in the signal? Yes you can do that.

Comment: Where would I first bring in the name for the new model, Insect?

Comment: You can first import the Insect model in the signal page,then get the list of Insect model whose name is similar to the bumblebee's name. Example: Insect.objects.filter(name=instance.bumblebee.name)

Comment: This was a huge help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you want a single object of Insect instead of list then use .get in place of .filter

Comment: XD i am glad that it helped you.