# How to create one to one field with Django for existing table?

Tags: django, database

We already have a model, let's say, `Product`. And we want to extend it into 'one to one relationship', let's say, `ProductDetails`.
How do it in such way, that for each existing row of `Product` model row `ProductDetails` is created automatically? with some default vaules.

Does Django provide such tool?
The task seems pretty regular for me, but I can't find any native solution.

Answer (score 1):

here is an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63323183/10602634

django signals can be used to create, update or delete on change of an object.

in your case:

```
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

class ProductDetails(models.Model):
    product =  models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    '''rest'''
```

wrap a function using receiver

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def add_details(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ProductDetails.objects.create(product=instance)
        return ProductDetails
```

django documnetation on receiver covers the topic https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/#receiver-functions

Comment: To be extra cautious, I would use `ProductDetails.objects.update_or_create()`